# Problem deploying application with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I have a web application that works perfectly for me in Eclipse, but unfortunately, I wanted to try it with the IntelliJ IDEA ultimate IDE, but I cannot run it, I have tried to deploy it in Tomcat and glassfish but I get an error trying to enter one of the views of the application and I do not understand why, if in eclipse I do not get these errors:

```
The error-page D:\Daniel\Documents\BM_SOFTWARE\Trabajos\proyectoBase\target\base\faces\views\404.xhtml or D:\faces\views\404.xhtml does not exist]]

  The error-page D:\Daniel\Documents\BM_SOFTWARE\Trabajos\proyectoBase\target\base\faces\views\404.xhtml or D:\faces\views\404.xhtml does not exist]]

Error Rendering View[/views/tytServiciosCreate.xhtml]
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name co.bmsoftware.i18n.labels, locale es
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationResourceBundle.getResourceBundle(ApplicationResourceBundle.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getResourceBundle(ApplicationAssociate.java:804)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getResourceBundle(ApplicationImpl.java:784)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getResourceBundle(ApplicationWrapper.java:586)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesResourceBundleELResolver.getValue(FacesResourceBundleELResolver.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:150)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:199)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:211)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:491)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

I would like to know why the difference in the deployments between IntelliJ and Eclipse, where in the latter I did not get any errors either when deploying or when entering the views.

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1

Comment: "works perfectly in Eclipse" what do mean by that? Have you tried using the web application in a browser? How are you 1. Packaging your application? 2. How are you deploying your application? Or have you simply configured Tomcat with intellij and deploy the application directly?

Comment: Some time ago I've recorded a video on how to deploy a Java EE/Jakarta EE application to Payara inside Intellij IDEA. If your application works on Glassfish, then it _should_ also run on Payara and you can take the video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2JbA7JlO6w

Comment: Seems there is similar issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243533